# No popup window with AngularJS and typeahead

Tags: angularjs, typeahead

I have a problem with the typeahead directive. I try to get datas from my datas from my service via $http.get.
In the console output I can see that my datas are coming from the service but I don't get the popup window of the results.

Here is my code:

Html Template:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Kundensuche" ng-model="selectedCompany" typeahead="c for c in companies($viewValue)" typeahead-no-results="noResults" typeahead-min-length="3">
```

Service:

```html
var _search = function (route, id) {
        return $http.get(serviceBase + 'api/' + route + '/search/' + id);        
    };

serviceHelperFactory.search = _search;
```

Controller:

```html
$scope.companies = function (val) {
              var output = [];
              var promise = serviceHelper.search('companies', val);
              promise.then(function (result) {
                  result.data.forEach(function (company) {
                                  output.push(company.companyName);
                                  //output.push(company);
                  });
                  console.log(output);                  
              }, function (error) {
                  adminInvoiceService.serviceErrorMessage(error);
              });
              return output;
          }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's your angularjs version and ui-bootstrap version? Your code works for after I change the 'typeahead="c for c in companies($viewValue)"' to 'uib-typeahead="c for c in companies($viewValue)"'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it!
For all with the same problem here is my solution!

```js
$scope.companies = function (val) {
              return $http.get('http://localhost:5569/api/companies/search/'+val).then(function (res) {
                  var companies = [];
                  console.log(companies);
                  res.data.forEach(function (item) {
                      companies.push(item);                      
                  });
                  console.log(companies);
                  return companies;
              });
          };
```